# How to rename file extentions in fish in a for loop?

Tags: fish

Here is the equivalent `bash` script that I am trying to convert to `fish`:

```
for j in *.md; do mv -v -- "$j" "${j%.md}.txt"; done
```

Here is what I tried:

```
for file in *.md
    mv -v -- "$file" "{{$file}%.md}.txt"
end
```

But it simply ends up renaming all of the files like so:

> ‘amazon.md’ -> ‘{{amazon.md}%.md}.txt’

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Why did I get a -1?

Comment: Have you read the manual? If yes, why do you expect unsupported syntax to work? If not, why don't you read the manual instead of asking nonsense here?

Comment: I tried a few things, and corrected the question. Thanks!

Comment: To which page of the fish documentation are you referring? Can you post a link?

Comment: `help expand-variable` and http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_loops

Comment: I cannot find the `${var%substr}` expansion there. Probably because it does not exist?

Comment: Okay. But I don't know that, which is why I'm posting a question here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118323/discussion-between-codehitman-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: Actually there is not much to discuss. The fish shell simply doesn't support parameter expansion like bash. Btw, I also never knew that before, but I think a quick look into the manual shows that clearly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to this:

```
for file in *.md
    mv -v -- "$file" (basename $file .md).txt 
end
```

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 11):

To do this just with fish:

```
for j in *.md
    mv -v -- $j (string replace -r '\.md$' .txt $j)
end
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer as it works with files in subdirectories (e.g. `/something/**/*.ext`)

Answer (score 3):

The fish shell doesn't support parameter expansion operations like bash. The philosophy of the fish shell to [let existing commands do the work instead of re-inventing the wheel](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand). You can use `sed` for example:

```
for file in *.md
    mv "$file" (echo "$file" | sed '$s/\.md$/.txt/')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another nice way to do this is with `string replace` command in fish as described in https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string-replace.html

```bash
for f in *.md; mv $f $(string replace ".md" ".txt" $f); end
```